# How to pass a date to a bash shell and calulcate from it?

Tags: bash

I am trying to pass a date string to a bash shell and calculate a new date from it, here is the test1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1"
MYDATE=$1
days = 5

echo $MYDATE

DATE_FROM=$($MYDATE "--date=-$days day" +%F)
```

and I call it with:

```
sh ./test1.sh 2017-07-10
```

it got following output:

```
2017-07-10
2017-07-10
./test1.sh: 8: ./test1.sh: 2017-07-10: not found
```

any idea ? thanks

Updated:
here is a working version based on @John Goofy:

```
#!/bin/bash

MYDATE="$1"
#DAYS=5      #or comment this line out and pass DAYS as argument $2


if [ -z "$2" ]; then
   DAYS = 10    
else  
   DAYS="$2"
fi 


NEWDATE=$(date --date="${MYDATE} + ${DAYS} day" +%Y-%m-%d)

echo $NEWDATE
```

calling this:

```
sh ./test1.sh 2017-07-10 5
```

days is set to 5, if calling it without $2, I'd like it to be 10, but got:

```
DAYS: not found
```

Comment: I'm really surprised you didn't also get `bash: days: command not found`.  What is the command `days` on your system?

Comment: @AngeloC, please have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

MYDATE="$1"
DAYS=5      #or use DAYS="$2"  to pass DAYS as argument $2

NEWDATE=$(date --date="${MYDATE} + ${DAYS} day" +%Y-%m-%d)

echo $NEWDATE
```

If you don't pass an argument the script will calculate from now.

Comment: making the days optional seems not working with following code: 
days = 0

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  days = 10  
  echo "empty"
else
  echo "not empty"
  days="$1"
fi 

echo $days

Comment: @AngeloC Please add your code effort to your OP and not any additional snippets into the comments, because I can't guess what you want or have.

Comment: How was your answer any different than mine (except posted 15 minutes later)? See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/how-should-we-deal-with-duplicate-answers) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266469/flag-duplicate-answers-on-the-same-question).

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a call to `date` command:

```
DATE_FROM=$(date --date "$MYDATE - $days day" +%F)
```

Also, to use a default value for `days`, you can use the [default value parameter expansion `${parameter:-word}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) (see [examples](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value)).

Additionally, since environment variables are ALL_CAPS as [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08), it's best to keep your [script variables in lowercase](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml#Naming_Conventions).

And note that the `+%Y-%m-%d` date format introduced in your update is *identical* to `+%F` (only more verbose).

All of this taken together yields a script that does what you need, and does it properly:

```
#!/bin/bash
start_date="$1"
days="${2:-10}"
end_date=$(date --date="${start_date} + ${days} day" +%F)
echo "${end_date}"
```

For example:

```
$ bash test1.sh 2017-07-10 5
2017-07-15
```

(Note that if you call your script with `sh` it doesn't matter that it has `bash` in hashbang, it's run with `sh`. Hashbang is only used if you make your script an executable with `chmod +x test1.sh` and then call it like `./test.sh ...`. Only then the shell will read from the hashbang which interpreter should use for the script.)